# How to describe this facial expression

Tags: american-english, writing

How would you describe a facial expression where someone goes "Eeehh.. not exactly." in response to a question. I'm not honestly sure where further I can explain what I mean, my brain is being....less dependable today.

Comment: Something like this [look (which is described as "puzzled")](https://www.dreamstime.com/puzzled-uncertain-black-girl-frowns-face-displeasure-feels-apathy-looks-uncertainty-cant-find-solution-way-out-image200286274)? If not, finding a picture would be helpful. Or describing the look (what are the lips and eyebrows doing?) or what it's supposed to convey (coyness? evasiveness?). This question as currently written is very unclear.

Comment: What emotion does "eeehh" represent? "Not exactly" could indicate someone is close or very far off, and indicate shock, bemusement, disgust, encouragement, patience, or a huge range of other mental states.

Comment: What makes you think it's describable? Most experiences aren't. Not even English has enough resources to represent everything.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps at all, my brain is working today, and I'm still not sure that there's a word capable of providing you with the "lightbulb moment" you may be hoping for. That I could think of, the closest matches for your premise are "tentative" or "hesitant".

ex: "Eh, not exactly," he said hesitantly.

"Uncertain" could also fit, depending on how one interprets the situation you're describing.

Comment: This actually is close enough. Essentially, the Character was hesitant to say to another Character about something that is really dark and rather something that would be better left unsaid.

So his reaction would be "Eeh..." With hesitance and then... "Not exactly.." I appreciate the help! But luckily I figured out what I was looking for that day. Probably my lowest and dumbest question yet lmao